# Swift - Cannot assign a value of type 'AEWebServices.Type' to a value of type 'NSXMLParserDelegate?'

Tags: xml, swift, nsxmlparser

I'm reading xml from a web service. I can display the xml successfully using println.  I am now trying to take the xml response and parse the individual elements using NSXMLParse.  This is my code:

```
public class AEWebServices : NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate
{
    var posts = NSMutableArray()
    var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
    var element = NSString()
    var nextItem = AEItem()

    var mutableData:NSMutableData  = NSMutableData.alloc()
    var currentElementName:NSString = ""
    var foundCharacters = ""
    var appParsedData = [Dictionary<String, String>]()
    var currentDataDictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()

    public class func performSearch(searchTerm : String, webService : String, resultsType : String) -> Bool{
        var serviceSuccess = false

        SRWebClient.GET(AEState.baseUrl + webService+"AccessKey="+AEState.accessKey+"&SearchTerm=" + searchTerm,
            success:{(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in
                //this is success part
                println("connection success - search successful")
                println(response)
                serviceSuccess=true
                let resultsData = response.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                var xmlparser = NSXMLParser(data: resultsData!)
                xmlparser.delegate = self
                xmlparser.parse()
                println("just after xml statement")
                //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showResults", sender: self)
            }, failure:{(error:NSError!) -> Void in
                //this is failure part
                println("connection failed - search failed")
                println(error)
        })
        return serviceSuccess
    }

    public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser,
        didStartElement elementName: String,
        namespaceURI: String!,
        qualifiedName qualifiedName: String?,
        attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
            println("in parser")
            println(elementName) // This line is never executed.
    }


    public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
        println("in parser 2")
        if !foundCharacters.isEmpty {
            currentDataDictionary[currentElementName as String] = foundCharacters
            foundCharacters = ""

            //Last Element so add to main Dictionary
            //Cannot find last element yet on XML so use Charge_GBP for testing until fixed
            if currentElementName == "Charge_GBP" {
                appParsedData.append(currentDataDictionary)
            }
        }
    }

    public func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?) {
        println("in parser 3")
        if (currentElementName == "Entry_ID") || (currentElementName == "Title") || currentElementName == "Description" || currentElementName == "Charge_USD" || currentElementName == "Charge_GBP" || currentElementName == "Classification_Type" {
            foundCharacters += string!
        }
    }

    public func parserDidEndDocument(parser: NSXMLParser) {
        println("in parser 4")
       // self.setupItemsOnView()

    }
}
```

My code is aiming to set up a class that will connect to a web service and, if successful, will receive the resulting xml information and parse it using NSXMLParser.  I am implementing the NSXMLParserDelegate but this line of code is causing me a problem:

xmlparser.delegate = self

The error I get is:
Cannot assign a value of type 'AEWebServices.Type' to a value of type 'NSXMLParserDelegate?'

I'm new to Swift, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious :-) Help appreciated.

Comment: You most likely will want to declare the `var xmlparser = NSXMLParser() xmlparser.delegate = self` block outside your closure, as self otherwise isn't accessible, and then find a way to pass the data to it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Claus - that solved my problem, which I've posted as an answer below.  If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Taking Claus Jorgensen's advice, took the declaration outside the closure to give this, which compiles and works:

var xmlParser: NSXMLParser!

public func performSearch(searchTerm : String, webService : String, resultsType : String) -> Bool {
    var serviceSuccess = false

```
SRWebClient.GET(AEState.baseUrl + webService+"AccessKey="+AEState.accessKey+"&SearchTerm=" + searchTerm,
    success:{(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in
        //this is success part
        println("connection success - search successful")
        println(response)
        serviceSuccess=true
        var resultsData = response.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        self.xmlParser = NSXMLParser(data: resultsData!)
        self.xmlParser.delegate = self
        self.xmlParser.parse()

        println("just after xml statement")
        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showResults", sender: self)
    }, failure:{(error:NSError!) -> Void in
        //this is failure part
        println("connection failed - search failed")
        println(error)
})
return serviceSuccess
```

}